# C++ builder - enumerate components on TPanel

Tags: components, c++builder, enumerate

It is quite simple to enumerate Form components

```
         for (int i=0;i<ComponentCount;i++)
         {
            ShowMessage(Components[i]->Name);
            //.....
         }
```

but the same thing does not work if I want to enumerate only the components which are located on Panel.

```
         for (int i=0;i<Panel1->ComponentCount;i++)
         {
            ShowMessage(Panel1->Components[i]->Name);
            //.....
         }
```

because

```
            Panel1->ComponentCount;
```

is just zero while having several components on Panel. So, how can I enumerate the child components of Panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ComponentCount` and `Components[]` properties access a component's list of **owned** components - components that have the component set as their `Owner` by having that component passed to their constructor.  All components created at design-time have the parent `TForm` (or `TFrame` or `TDataModule`) set as their `Owner`.  Your first loop is iterating through the TForm's owned components, that is why it works.  Your TPanel does not own any components, that is why the second loop fails.

What you are looking for is the `ControlCount` and `Controls[]` properties instead.  They access a visual control's list of **child** controls instead - controls that have the parent control set as their `Parent` for purposes of visual representation.  Only `TWinControl`-derived controls (like `TPanel`) can have child controls:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Panel1->ControlCount; ++i)
{
    ShowMessage(Panel1->Controls[i]->Name);
    //.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate all controls **AND** sub-controls (child controls of that control) of a form, panel, group box, etc:

```
void ExtractAll_Structure(TWinControl *container, int &indent)
{
   // Enumarate its children
   for (int i = 0; i < container->ControlCount; i++)
      {
      // extract the control at index i
      TComponent *child2 = container->Controls[i];

      if (child2->InheritsFrom (__classid(TComponent)) )  // this check if optional
         {
         Memo->Lines->Add(child2->Name);

         // Is this a container for other controls
         TWinControl *winctrl = dynamic_cast<TWinControl *>(child2);
         if (winctrl)
            {
            indent++;
            ExtractAll_Structure(winctrl, indent);
            indent--;
            }
         }
      }
}
```

Also see: 
[BCB : how to iterate over controls on a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391325/bcb-how-to-iterate-over-controls-on-a-form/52734942#52734942)